# Mocked ExecutorService always returns the same mocked Future

Tags: junit, future, executorservice, powermock, easymock

I implemented a mock ExecutorService to return the result instantly without the need to create threads:

```
public static ExecutorService createMock() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorServiceMock = EasyMock.createMock(ExecutorService.class);
    Future future = EasyMock.createMock(Future.class);
    Capture<Callable<?>> callableCapture = new Capture<>();
            EasyMock.expect(executorServiceMock.submit(EasyMock.<Callable<?>>capture(callableCapture))).andReturn(future).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(future.get()).andAnswer(() -> callableCapture.getValue().call()).anyTimes();

    executorServiceMock.shutdown();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes();
    EasyMock.replay(future, executorServiceMock);
    return executorServiceMock;
}
```

The problem is that it always returns the same [mocked] Future object. I need to return the new instance of Future mock based on the callable object passed to executorServiceMock.submit()
I tried to use PowerMock.expectNew(Future.class) but it complained "No constructor found in class 'java.util.concurrent.Future' with parameter types: [  ]"

Answer (score 0):

First of all ["Don't mock type you don't own!"](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own). By link you may find several reasons why you shouldn't do it.

But, if you really want to do it, then replace return mock via answer witch will create a new nock each time:

```
EasyMock.expect(executorServiceMock.submit(EasyMock.<Callable<?>>capture(callableCapture))).andAnswer(() -> {
    Future future = EasyMock.createMock(Future.class);
    EasyMock.expect(future.get()).andAnswer(() -> callableCapture.getValue().call()).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.replay(future);
    return future;
}).anyTimes();
```

By the way, you cannot expected `PowerMock.expectNew(Future.class)` because `Future`is interface and cannot be created.

Answer (score 0):

The capture will always return the last captured object. In your case, you seem to want to synchronize the submission and the get.

So, I think you should do the following:

```
    ExecutorService executorServiceMock = createMock(ExecutorService.class);

    expect(executorServiceMock.submit(EasyMock.<Callable<?>>anyObject()))
        .andAnswer(() -> {
            Future future = createMock(Future.class);
            Object value = ((Callable<?>) getCurrentArguments()[0]).call();
            expect(future.get()).andReturn(value);
            replay(future);
            return future;
        })
        .anyTimes();

    executorServiceMock.shutdown();
    expectLastCall().anyTimes();

    replay(executorServiceMock);

    return executorServiceMock;
```

Comment: In your case you expect the returned value is Integer. I want to return the same type mentioned in the callable

Comment: I returned an Integer because I tested it with an Integer. It can be more generic. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Below code fixed my issue.

```
@Mock
private ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool;

Future<String> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("S3PATH");
when(executorPool.submit(Mockito.<Callable<String>> anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
```